angular pagination not updating the page on clicking next page or previous page
I have angular pagination which does not fetch the next or previous page data on clicking the previous or the next button. Below is the child and parent code snippets. Any assistance is appreciated.
Pagination component.


export class PaginationComponent {
  @Input() totalCount?: number;
  @Input() pageSize!: number;
  @Input() pageNumber?: number;
  @Output() pageChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  get totalPages(): number {
    return Math.ceil(this.totalCount! / this.pageSize!);
  }

  changePage(page: number): void {
    if (page >= 1 && page <= this.totalPages) {
      this.pageNumber = page;
      this.pageChanged.emit(page);
    }
  }
}



Pagination template


<div class="pagination">
    <button (click)="changePage(pageNumber! - 1)" [disabled]="pageNumber === 1">Previous</button>
    <span>Page {{ pageNumber }} of {{ totalPages }}</span>
    <button (click)="changePage(pageNumber! + 1)" [disabled]="pageNumber === totalPages">Next</button>
</div>



Parent component


export class ShopComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  brands: Brands[] = [];
  types: Type[] = [];
  totalCount?: number;
  shopParams = new ShopParams();
  sortOptions = [
    { name: 'Alphabetical', value: 'name' },
    { name: 'Price: Low to High', value: 'priceAsc' },
    { name: 'Price: High to Low', value: 'priceDesc' },
  ];

  constructor(private shopService: ShopService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProducts();
    this.getBrands();
    this.getTypes();
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.shopService.getProducts(this.shopParams).subscribe((response) => {
      this.products = response.data;
      this.shopParams.pageIndex = response.pageIndex;
      this.shopParams.pageSize = response.pageSize;
      this.totalCount = response.count;
    });
  }
}



Parent component template


   <div
        class="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 2xl:grid-cols-5 gap-x-3 md:gap-x-5 xl:gap-x-7 gap-y-4 lg:gap-y-5 xl:gap-y-6 2xl:gap-y-8">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products">
            <app-product-item [product]="product"></app-product-item>
        </div>
    </div>




You are showing getProducts getting called from ngOnInit but nothing that is watching for changes is triggering a call to it?  Since this is quite a few parts that are working together too suggest throw together a stackblitz to accompany the code you shared here to show it "working" or rather not working.

The parent doesn't even include the PaginationComponent. There is too much missing to draw any conclusions. I second that a stackblitz is a good idea.
